# SMTP error with Rails Exception Notifier plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Working on OS X, trying to get Rails Exception Notifier plugin to send out emails. I have verified the following:

- I can successfully send email from my app
- I am creating a test error (`1/0` in one of my actions).
- Current plugin installed...

  script/plugin install git://github.com/rails/exception_notification.git
- In ApplicationController...

  include ExceptionNotifiable

  local_addresses.clear
- In environment.rb...

  ```
  Rails::Initializer.run do |config|

    # ...

    config.after_initialize do
      ExceptionNotifier.exception_recipients = %w(abc@gmail.com abc@abc.gov)
      ExceptionNotifier.sender_address = %("Contact DB error" <abc@abc.gov>)
      ExceptionNotifier.email_prefix = "[Contact DB error] "
    end

  end
  ```

In addition to the intentionally-created test error, I'm seeing this error on the console...

```
    Processing ApplicationController#index (for 127.0.0.1 at 2009-10-02 14:40:55) [GET]

    Net::SMTPFatalError (555 5.5.2 Syntax error. 3sm30577fge.12
    ):
      /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:680:in `check_response'
      /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:653:in `getok'
      /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:631:in `mailfrom'
      /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:544:in `send0'
      /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:472:in `sendmail'
      /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:379:in `start'
      haml (2.2.6) rails/./lib/sass/plugin/rails.rb:19:in `process'
```

Then it tries to send an exception notification for the SMTP error...

```
  Subject: [Contact DB error] application#index (Net::SMTPFatalError) "555 5.5.2 Syntax error. 3sm30577fge.12\n"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](http://osdir.com/ml/RubyonRailsTalk/2009-08/msg02472.html) seems to indicate it is related to your from address. Try changing it to just `abc@abc.gov`.

Comment: That page also indicates that the problem should have been fixed, but I'm seeing the same thing in Rails 2.3.5. Removing the angle brackets fixes the problem. Is this still broken?